# Problem:: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

[image]

I can't login my MySQL server. I got many solutions via the internet but not working any single solution.

Comment: There are lots of potential reasons for this error.  Specifically, what have you tried?

Comment: I replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to ensure that MySQL server is up and running. This procedure is different for different distros, but you can try

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

to start

Comment: [....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!

Comment: Ok so the server is not starting. Now you might want to run suggested commands `systemctl status mysql.service` and `journalctl -xe` and check for clues

Comment: istiyak-santo
    State: degraded
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 1 units
    Since: Tue 2018-11-20 19:51:07 +06; 1h 15min ago
   CGroup: /
           ├─user.slice
           │ └─user-1000.slice
           │   ├─user@1000.service
           │   │ ├─gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service
           │   │ │ └─3039 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
  ............

Comment: Also check `/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log`. Also, if it's possible, consider reinstalling MySQL from scratch

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is not starting.

As suggested, your first step is to bang out the typical commands: `service mysql status` and `journalctl -xe` to see what errors are reported.  The usual suspects are permissions on the mysql data folder typically located in/var/lib/mysql (permissions should be mysql:mysql) and also errors in my.cnf (/etc/mysql/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf for recent mariadb installs)

If your MySQL was previously running and now wont start, you might be dealing with table corruption.  Get mysqlcheck running on it if this is the case.  If you are going to attempt a database startup with innodb_force_recovery flag, make sure you have your data backed up prior to launching the database.

Let us know the output of these commands so we can further assist.